# Страница отображается без стилей

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Копирую с сайта getbootstrap.com исходник обьекта, вставляю к себе на страничку - обьект отображается но без стилей, выглядит кошмарно. Гемки ставил те, которые предлагались в скринкасте. Простите, может вопрос глупый задаю, я совершенно стерильный в плане программирования...

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, забыли стили подключить. Внимательно посмотрите ту часть скринкаста, где говорят про `app/assets/application.css`.